# Cypress - Use Chance JS to generate Data and store that Data for use later

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, cypress, chancejs

Essentially what I want to do is generate a name using ChanceJS for a test case within cypress, but in a separate file / test case I want to be able to recall that name that I generated earlier so I can select it / check it exists.

I have cut down these code snippets a fair bit so they wont make total sense.

I have tried having my own file with a constant in it called constants.js

```
    require('chance')
 export const constants = {
    ITEM: chance.word()
  }
```

and then having something like this in a test file where I add an item using the random name as its name

```
import { constants } from '../constants';
//Add Item
it('Add a Item', function(){
cy.pass_credentials()
cy.get('.dx-datagrid-toolbar-button > .dx-button-content > .dx-icon').click({force: true})
cy.get('[id$=_Name]').type(constants.ITEM) // using my random name for the item name
}
```

and then later I try to use it again to select the item in a separate file as the data I added in the previous file is now being used as part of this other piece of data

```
import { constants } from '../constants';
it('Add Data', function(){
cy.pass_credentials()
cy.get('[id$=_TaskId]').type(constants.ITEM)    //typing my random name in so I can select it as its now part of a drop making up this new piece of data  
cy.contains(constants.ITEM).type('{enter}')     //trying to press enter so I select my item
}
```

But the issue I am having is that it is generating a new random name which means im trying to select something that is not there. I'm not sure if every time I import it on a new file to be used that's what's causing it to re-generate?

I guess I could do with some pointers or a better solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to generate the item the first time and save it in `Cypress.env()` variable and then use it through out your test. `Cypress.env()` can be accessed by any tests throughout and also one value would be passed to all the tests for that execution cycle.

```js
import {constants} from '../constants'
//Add Item
it('Add a Item', function () {
  Cypress.env('uniqueItem', constants.ITEM) //Random item is set for this test run
  cy.pass_credentials()
  cy.get('.dx-datagrid-toolbar-button > .dx-button-content > .dx-icon').click({
    force: true,
  })
  cy.get('[id$=_Name]').type(Cypress.env('uniqueItem')) // types in the item
})
```

You test in next test suite. You don't need to call the import statements here and directly use the value using the `Cypress.env('uniqueItem')`.

```js
it('Add Data', function () {
  cy.pass_credentials()
  cy.get('[id$=_TaskId]').type(Cypress.env('uniqueItem'))
  cy.contains(Cypress.env('uniqueItem')).type('{enter}')
})
```

Comment: This seems to have resolved it, I guess I could forgo the constants file with this method and just generate the name within the first test.